# Segmentation Fault Using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to build my own library for using and scheduling threads.

The system is working in a way that you can `make maximum 100 threads`, making them "ready". and then there is a scheduler that each period of time, takes the active thread, put him in the ready list, and takes the first waiting thread in the ready list.

My tester is creating `500000` threads, and each thread creates a new thread and tries to terminate itself. the second thread(the the first thread creates) doing the same. and the third is only terminating itself.

This is the tester:

```
void f3()
{
    printf("f3 before terminate\n");
    uthread_terminate(uthread_get_tid());
    printf("f3 after terminate\n");
}

void f2()
{
    printf("f2 before spawn\n");
    uthread_spawn(f3);
    printf("f2 after spawn\n");
    uthread_terminate(uthread_get_tid());
    printf("f2 after termination\n");
}

void f1()
{
    printf("f1 before spawn\n");
    uthread_spawn(f2);
    printf("f1 after spawn\n");
    uthread_terminate(uthread_get_tid());
    printf("f1 after termination\n");
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printf("test8:\n--------------\n");
   cout << "* Output should be:\n";    
   cout << "--------------\n";
   cout << "***1***\n";
   cout << "***2***\n";
   cout << "Output is:\n";
   uthread_init(100);
   printf("***1***\n");
   for (volatile int i=0; i< 50000;++i){
        uthread_spawn(f1);
   }
   printf("***2***\n");

   uthread_terminate(0);
   return 0;
}
```

While my program gets "segmentation fault" when it enters my scheduler:

```
static void scheduler(){
DBG(("Schedular "))
nQuantum++;
if (ready.size()!=0){
    if (active != NULL){
        if (active->getState() == Thread::RUNNING){
            active->setState(Thread::READY);
            ready.push_back(active);
        }

        int val = sigsetjmp(*active->getEnv(),1);
        if (val !=0){
            blockTimerSignal(UNBLOCK);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Set new Active
    active = ready.front();
    DBG(("Active thread Id: %d",active->getTid()))
    ready.pop_front();
    DBG(("Doing pop front on ready list"))
    DBG(("Number of threads in ready list is  - %d",(ready.size())))
    active->setQuantums(active->getQuantums()+1);
    active->setState(Thread::RUNNING);
    setTimer();
    blockTimerSignal(UNBLOCK);
    DBG(("UNBLOCKED"))
    siglongjmp(*active->getEnv(),1);
    DBG(("After siglong jmp"))
}else{
    active->setQuantums(active->getQuantums()+1);
}
DBG(("Number of threads in ready list is  - %d",(ready.size())))

blockTimerSignal(UNBLOCK);
 }
```

When doing `siglongjmp(*active->getEnv(),1);`

It happens only for the main thread(The first thread of the program with id 0).
it also happens after the program runs for a while, meaning, in the middle of the program, it can do the siglongjmp for the active thread, but when it tries again after a time, it gives the error.

Adding my terminate function if helps:

```
int uthread_terminate(int tid) {
    DBG(("Terminate - %d", tid))

    if (tid == 0){
        // delete all (threads) - don't think it's needed because using stl!
        // TODO : check if needed - and then delete all lists !
        //Added by Roni - Deleting all lists!
        while(!sleeping.empty()){
            delete (sleeping.front());
            sleeping.pop_front();
        }

        while(!suspended.empty()){
            delete (suspended.front());
            suspended.pop_front();
        }

        while(!ready.empty()){
            delete (ready.front());
            ready.pop_front();
        }


        exit(0);
    }

    pThread t = getThread(tid);
    if (t == NULL){
        errmsgLibrary(THREAD_NOT_FOUND);
        return FAIL;
    }
    Thread::threadState state = t->getState();
    DBG(("Terminate - %d in State %d", tid, state))
    DBG(("Number of threads in ready list is  - %d",(ready.size())))
    blockTimerSignal(BLOCK);
    switch (state){
    case (Thread::RUNNING):
        //DBG(("Running Case"))
        //DBG(("Active thread id is: %d ",active->getTid()))
            delete active;
            active = NULL;
    //DBG(("Finsihed running Case"))
            scheduler();

            break;
    case (Thread::READY):
        //DBG(("ready Case"))
            ready.remove(t);
            delete t;
            //DBG(("Finsihed ready Case"))
        break;
    case (Thread::SLEEP):
            sleeping.remove(t);
            delete t;
        break;
    case (Thread::SUSPENDED):
            suspended.remove(t);
            delete t;
            break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    //DBG(("Number of threads in ready list is  - %d",(ready.size())))
    blockTimerSignal(UNBLOCK);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `active` must be `NULL` so caused `SIGSEGV` at that moment. You should check `uthread_spawn(f3);` is succeed or not every time you call it, since you might meet thread limit or out of memory so it failed.

Comment: @ReckHou Hou Hou Actually when I check I see only f1 in action. 
What does it mean? what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, You're using `siglongjmp` here, and probably aren't changing stacks between the calls.

Consider using [`getcontext()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcontext.2.html), [`swapcontext()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/swapcontext.3.html) and [`makecontext()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/makecontext.3.html) instead.